# How to focus on component

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I am using 'keen-ui' library in my project. Here is [special component](https://josephuspaye.github.io/Keen-UI/#/ui-select) for select item. I want to handle event from another component and set focus on this, but I don't know how to.

Another components, that have inside `<input/>` tag can be focused like `this.$refs[component name].$el.children[0].children[1].focus`, where `children[0].children[1]` is `<input/>` element. This is ugly, but if the component doesn't contain input tag, we can not do even this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Examining the widgets, I see that they contain a `div` with `tabindex="0"`, which means they can receive focus.

If you have a `ref` on the component, you should be able to do something like

```
const focusableEl = this.$refs.uiselect.querySelector('[tabindex="0"]');
focusableEl.dispatchEvent(new Event('focus'));
```

and the widget will light up. I actually did that from the console to test it out. Interestingly, `blur` did not work for me.